# Insert a bunch of duplicate rows into a mysql table

Tags: mysql, insert

I need to insert 50 rows into a mysql table. They should all be exactly identical, besides the primary key.

Is there a query that can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Just use while loop:

```
declare var1 int
select var1 = 0
BEGIN 
 WHILE (var1 < 50) DO 
   insert...
   Select var1 = var1 + 1
 END WHILE;
END
```

Comment: Hmm. Tried it out, but the insert statement isn't working (it spits out an error, pointing to the insert statement and tells me to check my syntax there). I'm using `INSERT INTO myTable (data,num) VALUES ('textdata',1234)`. Weird thing is, that works fine on its own as a single insert. Any ideas?

Comment: As well, how do i increment the var1 counter?

Comment: Is your primary key an auto increment?

Answer (score 0):

Brutal but efficient:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (data, num)
SELECT 'textdata' as data, 1234 as num
FROM
( SELECT 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1
) as a,
( SELECT 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1
) as b,
( SELECT 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1
) as c
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a random existing table that has more rows than you want to insert, you could do this:

> insert into table1 (row1,row2) select *identical value1*, *identical value2* from table2 limit 50

e.g.:

> insert into table1 (myint, mystr, mystr2) select 123, "hello", "world"
>   from table2 limit 50

- Note that you are not actually inserting anything from table2