# MySQL. Insert to database multiple duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, duplicates, multiple-instances

I need to do simple thing, insert multiple (100) rows, they can be identical as first line.

For example: John 20 (I need insert these 2 values 100 time)

I found here php query method: 
[Insert a bunch of duplicate rows into a mysql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620198/insert-a-bunch-of-duplicate-rows-into-a-mysql-table)

Is it possible to make it by SQL command?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
INSERT INTO "my_table" 
VALUES
( 'dataset1'),
( 'dataset2'),
( '...'),
-- ....
;
```

This can be created e.g. via a shell script or your editor of choice etc.